# Create, update, modify, and delete UEFI authenticated variables from userspace in Linux

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

I've been searching for, but cannot find any information or utilities for creating, deleting, modifying, and updating arbitrary authenticated variables in Linux from userspace.

Sure, there are tools like `sbvarsign` for signing updates to authenticated variables, but I suspect `sbvarsign` is just for secure boot variables. Even if it is for other variables, it provides no facilities creating/deleting variabled and it only creates blobs instead of actually applying those signed updates.

How can I create, delete, update, and modify authenticated variables by any name in Linux userspace? Furthermore, is there a way to determine from userspace if a platform's firmware supports authenticated variables?